# Searching by xPath element in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, element

Have a div with following content.
Could anyone please advice how could I find eg. `<dd>ID</dd>` with `<dt>jankovalsky</dt>` and perform .getText on it ?

```
<dl id="userDetails" class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Forename</dt>
    <dd></dd>
    <dt>Surname</dt>
    <dd></dd>
    <dt>ID</dt>
    <dd>jankovalsky</dd>
    <dt>Preferred Language</dt>
    <dd></dd>
    <dt>Position</dt>
    <dd></dd>
    <dt>Accounts in domains</dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
                <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
    <dt>Business roles</dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </dd>
    <dt>email</dt>
    <dd></dd>
    <dt>Status</dt>
    <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

As for `<dt></dt>`  did id by xpath like `@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"userDetails\"]/dt[3]")`  but need more universal way to identify it in case of some change of `<dt>ID</dt>` ordering (cause it's enough that in next build it will land as the first one and assertion will be failed).

And no idea how to deal with this `<dd>jankovalsky</dd>`

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for the `<dd>` that has `jankovalsky`, or do you just want the text content of whatever `<dd>` follows `<dt>ID</dt>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `following-sibling` here:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dl[@id='userDetails']/dt[. = 'ID']/following-sibling::dd")).getText();
```